# Zend form input box aligning

Tags: html, zend-form

This is my HTML view:

```
<tr class="header">
    <th>CLASS</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
</tr>

<?php 

foreach($this->documents as $row): ?>

<tr>

    <td><?php echo $row['CLASS'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['NAME'];?></td>
            href="/admin/documents/delete?ID=<?php echo $row['ID'];?>">
        delete</a> 
    </td>   
</tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>

</table>
</div>
```

This is my view Form:

```
public function init()
{

    $CLASS = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('CLASS');
    $CLASS->setLabel('CLASS')
            ->setRequired(true);


    $NAME = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('NAME');
    $NAME->setLabel('NAME')
            ->setRequired(true);

    $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('Submit');
    $submit->setAttrib('ID', 'submitbutton');

    $this->addElements(array($CLASS, $NAME,$submit));
}
```

[image: Zend Form front view]

I have zend form, having two inputs CLASS and NAME. 
How to display CLASS and required input text box column in the same line?

This is my output image:
[image: required output image]

And same thing, how to put submit and Reset button in the same line?

Comment: Please provide your code, else nobody can guess whats going on

Comment: Hi Sudarshan, Hi Added i form view code kindly help on this ?

Comment: can you just do inspect element and copy that html code and paste in your answer? that will really help me to align your code in line. Else if you are using boostrap try giving class to <form class="form-inline">, please give your html code

Comment: Hi Sudarshan html code added

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dyfbLx4z/ check this fiddle you need to align your code in this format, I mean you need to give same html structure in your zend form https://jsfiddle.net/dyfbLx4z/1/ this one without border

Comment: check this one also https://jsfiddle.net/dyfbLx4z/2/

Comment: hey did this worked?

Comment: Hi Sudarshan, i was added my output i want to modify the my output in this design.

Comment: you run your code then inspect element and right click in it and choose edit then copy whole code from browser and paste here, did you understand?

Comment: Hi Sudarshan, thanks lot i explore the my browser then i created css style sheet for align input boxes. Now it is working how i expected. Thanks lot for you help.

Comment: shall I post this as an answer then will you accept it?